# Como instalar o pip para uma determinada versão do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Tenho o ubuntu 17.10 instalado e ele veio com o Python 2.7 e 3.6.

Instalei o Python 3.4 mas não consigo instalar o pip nele, ele sempre vai para a versão mais recente com o pip3 que é a 3.6 Como posso fazer para instalar na 3.4?

Comment: Como você instalou o Python 3.4?

Comment: no terminal sudo apt-get install python3.4. depois no terminal cd /usr/src descompactei o arquivo Python-3.4.4.tgz com tar txzf Python-3.4.4 e usei os comandos ./configure depois make, make test e depois sudo make install

Comment: Primeiro verifica qual a versão do Python atualmente rodando com `python --version` e nos diz por favor.

Comment: É a 3.4.4 isso pq eu editei a debian_defaults colocando defaults_version=python3.4 localizada em /usr/share/python e criei o link simbolico  sudo rm /usr/bin/python (esse foi pra remover o link) e usei ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 4):

Eu recomendo rodar o script [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) como descrito na [documentação deles](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py).

Simplismente baixe o arquivo e rode usando o python que você quer que tenha o pip:

```
python get-pip.py
```

ou

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

ou

```
python2 get-pip.py
```

ou usando o path completo se você instalou o python sozinho por exemplo:

```
/home/avraham/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.4.6/bin/python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Tentei executar o get-pip.py com o comando python3.4 get-pip e aparece a seguinte mensagem `python3.4 can't open file 'get-pip.py' no such file or diretory`. Também não consegui localizar a pasta oculta pelo terminal (.pythonz).como devo proceder?

Comment: Outra observação entrei no local onde está o get-pip.py e tentei executar com o python3.4 e aparece a msg zipimport.zipimporterror: can't decompress data; zlib not avaible. Instalei o zlib1g mas ainda ocorre essa msg

Comment: O meu python 3.4 esta em /usr/local ele também veio com a pasta ensure pip nele tem dois pacotes whl pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl como posso descompactar pelo terminal?

Comment: provavelmente você teria que recompilar o python. eu recomendo usar o pythonz, ele simplifica muito a vida, ele baixa e compila a versão especifica que você quer

Comment: Obrigado tovmeod's tive que recompilar o python mesmo. Mas usei o virtualvenv para conseguir instalar os pacotes q eu queria no 3.4. Vou deixar assim se mais gente tiver esse problema. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seu problema seja resolvido nesse site: https://github.com/Langoor2/PokemonGo-Map-FAQ/wiki/%27python---pip%27-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command,-operable-program-or-batch-file.